# Javascript calculate date week by week

Tags: javascript, date

Hy guys,
i have write this javascript code for calculate date for any day of week progressively.
But i ahve error when the code must be calculate the end of month: example after 31/07/2'15 the code generate 32/07/2015 instead 01/08/2015.
This is my code:

```
var application = this;
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var stringDate1 = currentDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
        var stringDate2 = (currentDate.getUTCDate()+1) + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
        var stringDate3 = (currentDate.getUTCDate() + 2) + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
        var stringDate4 = (currentDate.getUTCDate() + 3) + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
        var stringDate5 = (currentDate.getUTCDate() + 4) + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
        var stringDate6 = (currentDate.getUTCDate() + 5) + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
        var stringDate7 = (currentDate.getUTCDate() + 6) + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
```

where my code is wrong?
Any help please?
BR

Comment: Are you trying to get the dates for today and the next 6 days? Either way, the way you are trying to achieve this is far too complicated.

Comment: Yes, my code calculate the date for today and for the 6 next days.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds` to today's date, and you get tomorrow's date, and so on.

```
var tomorrowsDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the date for one day ahead you can use [`Date.prototype.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

So to calculate all dates from today and week ahead, you can do something like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var stringDate = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    stringDate[i] = currentDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
}

console.log(stringDate);

// 0: "28/7/2015"
// 1: "29/7/2015"
// 2: "30/7/2015"
// 3: "31/7/2015"
// 4: "1/8/2015"
// 5: "2/8/2015"
// 6: "3/8/2015"
```

Comment: Ok thanks but i need for each day a variable string, so i must create 6 variable with the array. example: stringDate1 = stringDate(0), stringDate2 = stringDate(1) ect etc

Comment: @dev_ Just access it like stringDate[0] for today, stringDate[1] for tomorrow and so on

Comment: Yes, i jìhave associated the array to singles variable. Thanks for your help