# get Date between 2 dates in jquery with format (dddd MMMM Do, YYYY)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently I'm using [jQuery Date Range Picker](https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/)

Now I have 2 dates:

Start date="Wednesday July 29th, 2015"

End dates="Wednesday August 5th, 2015"

So now I'm trying to get and display dates between start date and End date with "dddd MMMM Do, YYYY" format 
same date format mentaion for startdate

Expected o/p:-

Wednesday July 29th, 2015

Thursday July 30th, 2015

Friday July 31st, 2015

Saturday August 1st, 2015

Sunday August 2nd, 2015

Monday August 3rd, 2015

Tuesday August 4th, 2015

### Wednesday August 5th, 2015

---

Comment: have you tried anything yet? you probably want to take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: yes i tried moment.js but , not getting any success..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript calculate date week by week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653688/javascript-calculate-date-week-by-week)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy to achieve with moment:

```
var Start_date="Wednesday July 29th, 2015"
var End_date="Wednesday August 5th, 2015"

var start=moment(Start_date, "dddd MMMM Do, YYYY")
var end = moment(End_date, "dddd MMMM Do, YYYY")
console.log(start,end)

var today = start
while (today <= end){
    console.log(today.format("dddd MMMM Do, YYYY"));
    today = today.add(1, "days");
}
```

Output:

```
"Wednesday July 29th, 2015" 
"Thursday July 30th, 2015" 
"Friday July 31st, 2015" 
"Saturday August 1st, 2015"
"Sunday August 2nd, 2015" 
"Monday August 3rd, 2015" 
"Tuesday August 4th, 2015" 
"Wednesday August 5th, 2015"
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ujksLap/